# Using selenium webdriver to get login to popup via click

Tags: asp.net, web, driver

**I am writing a test script using Selenium web driver (IE). I had no luck trying to get a popup login to display (in iframe) via click. It is an asp.net web application and this is the html that is rendered:**

```
<span class='loggedOut'> 
                    <a class='logInOut logIn popupLink' href='#'>Log In</a>

                    <span class='divider mini-hidden'>|</span>

                    <a class='logInOut register mini-hidden' href='/Forms/Registration.aspx'>Register</a>

                </span>
```

**This is the selenuim syntax that I have used, nothing worked:**

```
lbi.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='logInOut logIn popupLink']")).click();
```

or

```
lbi.findElement(By.classname("logInOut logIn popupLink")).click();
```

or

```
lbi.findElement(By.ByLinkText("Log In")).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add to use .sendkeys method and send "Enter" as a key. It did the trick in IE8.